# Detect "Crater" Jumps In Non-Linear Lidar Distance Data

Tags: image-processing, point, lidar

[Graph of points polar coordinate radius value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n9sc.png)

I'm trying to detect groups of points in this stream of lidar data. It's 360 points per revolution and the graph is one revolution. I have a list of points in python and I'm trying to split it into a list of lists of points where each sublist is a group of points that are clustered together. Essentially I'm trying to split the main group where the discontinuities of the graph are.

I've tried the sliding window method to detect where the derivative between the points is above the mean derivative for the window, but it is not giving consistent nor correct results.

```
    def DetectClusters(self, Points, WindowScale=0.1):
        """Takes a list of points and returns a list of lists of points that are clustered together.
            Uses sliding window algorithm to detect clusters.

        Args:
            Points (Position): List of points to be clustered.
            WindowScale (float, optional): The scale of the window to be used for clustering. Defaults to 0.1, 10% of the dataset.

        Returns:
            List: List of lists of points that are clustered together.
        """

        WindowIndex = 0

        ClusterEndPoints = []

        while WindowIndex + int(len(Points) * WindowScale) < len(Points):
            Window = Points[
                WindowIndex : WindowIndex + int(len(Points) * WindowScale)
            ]  # Get the window of points

            WindowRadii = []
            for i in range(len(Window) - 1):
                WindowRadii.append(
                    Window[1].GetROnly()
                    )
                )  # Get the radii of the window

            WindowRadii.append(
                math.sqrt(Window[1].GetROnly()
            )

            WindowRadiiDerivative = []
            for i in range(len(WindowRadii) - 1):
                WindowRadiiDerivative.append(
                    WindowRadii[i + 1] - WindowRadii[i]
                )  # Get the derivative of the radii

            # add the last point to the derivative list
            WindowRadiiDerivative.append(WindowRadii[0] - WindowRadii[-1])

            AbsoluteWindowRadiiDerivative = [
                abs(derivative) for derivative in WindowRadiiDerivative
            ]  # Get the absolute value of the derivative

            AbsoluteWindowRadiiDerivativeMean = (
                self.Mean(AbsoluteWindowRadiiDerivative) * 1.5
            )  # Get the mean of the absolute value of the derivative

            for i in range(len(Window)):
                if AbsoluteWindowRadiiDerivative[i] > AbsoluteWindowRadiiDerivativeMean:
                    ClusterEndPoints.append(
                        WindowIndex + i
                    )  # If the derivative is greater than the mean, it is likely a cluster end point

            WindowIndex += 1

        ClusterEndPoints = list(set(ClusterEndPoints))  # Remove duplicates

        Clusters = []
        for i in range(len(ClusterEndPoints) - 1):
            Clusters.append(
                Points[ClusterEndPoints[i] : ClusterEndPoints[i + 1]]
            )  # Get the clusters

        if ClusterEndPoints[0] > 2:
            Clusters.insert(0, Points[: ClusterEndPoints[0]])  # Get the first cluster if it exists

        return Clusters
```

Any suggestions on methods I could use? I'm trying to avoid the python Open CV library because it will be ported to C++ eventually.

The next steps are to classify what the clusters of points are, but that is taken care of already.